# Matching regular expression OR and AND

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to match the 1s OR (AND) 0s using a regular expression.

For example

```
^((1+|0+)|(1*,0*))1((1+|0+)|(1*,0*))1+((1+|0+)|(1*,0*))$
```

matches `01001110`.
I would like to know how to match `"either series of 1 or series of 0 or mixed series of 1 and 0"`

I have tried the following and doesn't work for string `1010`.

```
^((1+|0+)|(1*,0*))1+((1+|0+)|(1*,0*))$
```

The idea is that in [this](https://www.codeeval.com/browse/130/) problem,  "A"s can be represented as 1+ OR 0+ or mix of both.
So I'm trying to derive the regular expression as shown above.

Comment: Do you mean **alternate** series of 1s and 0s, like in 01010101...?

Comment: What's wrong with `[01]+`

Comment: It would help a lot if you would post example of input, point which parts should be matched by regex and which should be skipped (and why). Otherwise it looks like simple `[01]+` is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you want but if you want to find series which contains only `1` and/or `0` then your regex can look like `(1|0)+` which can be also written using [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) as `[01]+`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just matching binary digits, you can use:

```
Pattern any = Pattern.compile("[01]+");
```

If you want alternate binary digits, you can use:

```
Pattern alt = Pattern.compile("((?<=0|^)1|1(?=0|$))+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
^([0,1]+)$
```

Try this site for further tests:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html